# Firefox - Opening the context menu triggers a scroll event

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, mozilla

We have a div where overflow is hidden by default and the class makes it as `overflow: auto` on hover.

We have our context menu defined for the div. There are events registered to hide the context menu on the loss of focus or if there is a scroll after opening the menu.

Everything is working fine with all browser except firefox and the issue is:-

While we are on the div the scrollbar is visible as expected, as soon as right click is done, the context menu opens and closes suddenly.

Tried debugging the issue and found that a scroll event is coming as soon as I right click which then runs a code to hide the menu.

I Could not find what is causing this. If I simply remove overflow hidden it works fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, I don't have your custom context menu, though.

Comment: could you give a working demo

Comment: Sharing a link below.There is no context menu but a scroll is getting triggered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53608738/overflowauto-from-overflowhidden-in-firefox-is-triggering-a-scroll-event